# How to add an anchor tag in yaml content of html file for jekyll project

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll

I am new to Jekyll and I have the following error

So I have a Jekyll project which has an index.html file,
the html file has content in yaml format in the front matter.
I would like to add an `<a href="">` tag to a word, to make it clickable and work as a link but upon adding the tag I get the following error

"YAML Exception reading /Users/yapsody/Desktop/campaigns.yapsody.com/faq/index.html: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 38 column 5"

this is my YAML content in index.html file, the content is at the top of the page, I would like to enclose "Dashboard overview" in the anchor tag

[image]

this is how I call my yaml content:

[image]

what I would like to do is the following or something that gives me the same output (dashboard overview ) but its giving me the following error (yellow text)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can add the link:

```
- title: HTML
  url: /html/
```

You can break a content and use the above way.
Please let me know if you find any issue

Comment: so I know this method, but it won't work for me since I am running a loop for faq cards, and not all cards will have "dashboard overview" hyperlinked in the paragraph
here's a link to the site, its live
https://campaigns.yapsody.com/faq/

Comment: Please check this link: https://idratherbewriting.com/jekylldoctheme-separate-outputs/mydoc/mydoc_hyperlinks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> [your text](your link)

example

> [google](https://google.com)

and after that, you are fetching this on your front end so you need to add a tag

> {{faq.question | markdownify }}

Hope this will help you
for more [https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#:~:text=Don%27t%20do%20this!-,Links,-To%20create%20a](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#:%7E:text=Don%27t%20do%20this!-,Links,-To%20create%20a)